# create a map for navigation from points?

Tags: ros, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I would like to create a map (pgm image and related yaml file) for robot navigation.
I need to create the map inside a python code where I have all the points of interest available such as room size, position and orientation of obstacles (fixed), etc...
basically i need to create a function that create a map (pgm image) from some points, for example if i have the vertices of an obstacle i need to create a shape with black outline and grey inside and so on....
Can anyone give me some guidance?

(ps: i use python with ros noetic)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393988/create-a-map-for-navigation-from-points?/) by [Misrek](https://answers.ros.org/users/92782/misrek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-01-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This [netpbmfile library](https://pypi.org/project/netpbmfile/) could help you generate your PGM map file with *.yaml file too ([documentation of YAML format for ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server))- then you can go with steps from [this YT tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWrvDUYAFBI) to load this map inside ROS1 Navigation stack.

EDIT:
Example usage:
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Misrek](https://answers.ros.org/users/92782/misrek/) on 2022-01-10**:
Thank you for your reply, I will study the library you have indicated.
I have only a small problem: I installed the library with "pip install netpbmfile" as indicated in the page but the import does not work in python.... I don't understand if the import is netpbm or netpbmfile, but neither works (Import "netpbm" could not be resolved, same for netpbmfile).

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-01-10**:
I edited the answer with example from documentation :)

**Comment by [Misrek](https://answers.ros.org/users/92782/misrek/) on 2022-01-10**:
I keep getting a warning about the import, but it works. Thanks for your help.